# Cross-browser jQuery incompatibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page has a set of links in a column on the left and a section with text on the right.  The text section is marked with a placeholder called "MTX" which is replaced with content on page load and when any of the links is clicked (the links are all button clicks that call the function ShowMainText).  It works fine in all Firefox versions from 56 up, but it doesn't work in Chrome or Safari browsers, or in the Apple iPhone browser.

Here is the code for the div tag:

```
<div class="main_text">
    <div id="C2"><span style="color:black">MTX</span></div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
function ShowMainText(type) {
    var filename = "text_" + type + ".htm"
    $( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
}
</script>
```

Here is the C2 ID css code:

```
#C2{
    color: rgb(117,163,126);
    font-family: camphorW01-Light,calibri,arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width: auto;
}
```

Here is the main_text class css code:

```
.main_text {
    grid-column: 8 / 14;
    grid-row: 6 / 19;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: left;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

I think this is an issue with the jQuery line `$( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);`, but I don't know exactly what's wrong.

This code comes from a much larger project.  If a complete reproducible example is needed to answer this question, I can create one and post it, but I hoped someone would know the answer because the issue seems to be limited to one line.

EDIT:  Chrome 66 dev console shows this:  Uncaught ReferenceError:  ShowMainText is not defined at onload.  index.htm(27).  Here's line 27:  body onload="ShowMainText(1); LinkLight();" onclick="HideDropdown_B(event); changeColor(event); changeColorBDD(event); getLastGAE(event); getFocusElement(event);">.  That seems to be the problem -- Chrome 66 doesn't find this on page load, but Firefox does.  I'm working on it but I'll appreciate any ideas.  Thanks.

Comment: Your `ShowMainText` function is missing a closing `}` Have you learned how to use Developer Console in your browser? Does it shows any errors? Have you placed your script tags before the closing `</body>` tag?

Comment: That's actually in the code but it seems to have been deleted before I posted this, so I edited it.  Thanks for pointing that out.  As I said, it works in Firefox.

Comment: Check browser developer console network tab - could be that it can't find the file in some browsers (path issue?)

Comment: Yes, I was just about to post this.  The Chrome 66 dev console shows an error.  I just edited the code to add this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `fadeIn` to happen after the elements have been loaded, you have to wait for them to be loaded by using [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)'s completion callback.

```
$("#C2").hide().load(filename, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(500);
});
```

You can use the arguments to the callback to know whether the `load` succeeded, see the docs for details.

Comment: Thanks, T.J.  I'll try this now and let you know.

Comment: No, still doesn't work in Chrome.  I'm still working on this.

Comment: @RTC222 - All due respect, yes, it does. Your edit completely changes the question, and introduces an error completely unrelated to the code you've shown. Apparently, that `script` tag isn't being processed by Chrome, which means that it's not correctly included on the page or that the `}` really is missing (make sure you clear cache). Chrome is not broken. :-)

Comment: Thanks, and you are right.  I will try your code again after I fix the onload issue.

Comment: Further evidence that your answer is correct:  when I comment out your line and revert to the original line (the one shown above that works in Firefox), I do not get the error re body onload.  I'm still working on the body onload issue, I''ll post back when I have an answer.